# Ruby on Rails: using near method with an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, geocoding

I have an association, but I'm trying to figure out how to get an array of the nearby users if I have this setup:

claim_controller.rb

```
def claim
  @claim = Claim.find_by_object_id(params[:object_id])
  @array = Claim.where(object_id: params[:object_id])
end
```

claim.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb

```
has_many :claims, dependent: :destroy
has_many :object_id, dependent: :destroy
```

view

```
<% @array.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.user.first_name %>
  <br>
  <%= p.user.street %>
  <%= p.user.city %>
  <hr>
<% end %>
```

my user database has `street`, `city`, `zip`, `state` columns. I need help figuring out the logic in getting nearby locations if I'm displaying the user's information through `claim`.

I know I could do something like `Claim.near(params[:location])`, but because the address is in the Users model, I would need to do something like `User.near(params[:location])`, however, I'm getting data based on the `params[object_id]` from `claim` model. I don't know how to get the `@array` that is associated to the nearby location.

---

So the idea of this is that there's a bunch of data in `Claims` model, and there are columns: `object_id` and `user_id`. Based on the id of the page, `params[:object_id]`, I'll be able to get all the users that claims to have that object, but I only want to show the users based nearby location as well,

Comment: You have to get the User of the claim first, `Claim.user`, get the location, translate it into latitude and longitude with geolocation (Google Maps), then use the Haversine formula to compute the distance of all other Users, and select only the Users that are within the specified distance, then collect all of the Claims from those Users.

Comment: @Chloe I can't do Claim.user, because its an array of users I'm getting from the `object_id` of the `Claim`. and I'm trying to collect all the `Users` from that `Claim`, not the other way around.

Comment: You have `claim.rb: belongs_to :user`, so you can call `@claim.user`. `find_by...` only returns 1 result anyways. Experiment in `rails console`.

Comment: @Chloe thats why I have `p.user` which is from `@array`. Can you give me an example?